# ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: - problem when I try to insert data in two children tables

Tags: mysql

I need some help with MySQL. I created four tables:
a parent table and three child table. I was able to insert data into the parent table and one of the children table, the simplest of them.
Now I try to introduce data in the other two children table, witch are connected to the parent table by foreign keys, and I can't do it because the system show me this message:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`world`.`firm`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Administrator`
> FOREIGN KEY (`administrator_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`ID`) ON DELETE
> CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

These are the four table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `height` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CNP` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Modified_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CNP` (`CNP`)

CREATE TABLE `firm` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `administrator_id` int NOT NULL,
  `firm_cache_value` int NOT NULL,
  `address` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_Administrator` (`administrator_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Administrator` FOREIGN KEY (`administrator_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE `work_history` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `started_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ended_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` int NOT NULL,
  `firm_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_person` (`person_id`),
  KEY `fk_firm` (`firm_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_firm` FOREIGN KEY (`firm_id`) REFERENCES `firm` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`ID`)

CREATE TABLE `car` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk_owner_id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_owner_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `person` (`ID`)
```

I succeded to insert data in person table:

```
select * from person;
+----+--------+------+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | height | age  | NAME  | CNP       | Created_at          | Modified_at         |
+----+--------+------+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    188 |   27 | Ionut | 195052203 | 2015-10-23 00:00:00 | 2022-09-27 00:00:00 |
|  2 |    173 |   28 | Maria | 294030228 | 2015-08-19 00:00:00 | 2022-09-18 00:00:00 |
|  3 |    179 |   25 | Radu  | 198102816 | 2017-11-14 00:00:00 | 2022-08-23 00:00:00 |
|  4 |    182 |   29 | Felix | 193121240 | 2014-03-22 00:00:00 | 2022-10-22 00:00:00 |
+----+--------+------+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Also I was able to insert data in car table:

```
select * from car;
+----+-------------------+
| id | model             |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Kia Sorento       |
|  2 | Fiat 500          |
|  3 | Skoda Superb      |
|  4 | VW Passat         |
|  1 | Kia Sorento       |
|  3 | Ford Mondeo       |
|  4 | Mercedes CLS      |
|  2 | Mini Clubman      |
|  3 | Dacia Duster      |
|  4 | Dacia Duster      |
|  2 | Mercedes C Classe |
+----+-------------------+
```

Now I am trying to insert data in work_history and firm tables and the system does not allow me it.
These are data I tried to insert:

```
insert into firm(name, created_at, administrator_id, firm_cache_value, address) 
values('Endava', '1998.05.20', '2277543', '10345976', 'Bucharest Avenue, no. 1, Pitesti city'), 
insert into work_history (started_at, ended_at, person_id, firm_id)
values ('2015.10.23', '2017.08.25', '1', '20745');
```

I am a begineer to mysql, so appreciate your hints.

Comment: Unreadable. Format please.

Comment: Apart from the multiple errors in the create table statements the error is quite clear the values doesn't exists on parent tables https://dbfiddle.uk/iMRESt7J